# Creating identifiers containing universal character names via token concatenation

Tags: c, clang, language-lawyer

I wrote this code that creates identifiers containing universal character names via token concatenation.

```
//#include <stdio.h>
int printf(const char*, ...);

#define CAT(a, b) a ## b

int main(void) {
    //int \u306d\u3053 = 10;
    int CAT(\u306d, \u3053) = 10;

    printf("%d\n", \u306d\u3053);
    //printf("%d\n", CAT(\u306d, \u3053));

    return 0;
}
```

This code worked well with [gcc 4.8.2 with `-fextended-identifiers` option](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/v4MhEWFYKdvIXwJY) and [gcc 5.3.1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcDI0cFdHSGNlY0k), but didn't work with [clang 3.3](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xdxfytlCfYuZsc6G) with error message:

```
prog.c:10:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ねこ'
        printf("%d\n", \u306d\u3053);
                       ^
1 error generated.
```

and local clang (Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)) with error message:

```
$ clang -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -o uctest1 uctest1.c
warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      '<dependent type>' [-Wformat]
uctest1.c:10:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ねこ'
        printf("%d\n", \u306d\u3053);
                       ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

When I used `-E` option to have the compilers output code with macro expanded,  gcc 5.3.1 emitted this:

```
# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "main.c"

int printf(const char*, ...);



int main(void) {

 int \U0000306d\U00003053 = 10;

 printf("%d\n", \U0000306d\U00003053);


 return 0;
}
```

local clang emitted this:

```
# 1 "uctest1.c"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 326 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "uctest1.c" 2

int printf(const char*, ...);



int main(void) {

 int \u306d\u3053 = 10;

 printf("%d\n", ねこ);


 return 0;
}
```

As you see, the identifiers declared and used in `printf()` matches in gcc's output, but they don't match in clang's output.

I know that creating universal character names via token concatenation invokes undefined behavior.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 5.1.1.2 Translation phases:

> If a character sequence that
>   matches the syntax of a universal character name is produced by token
>   concatenation (6.10.3.3), the behavior is undefined.

I thought that this character sequence `\u306d\u3053` may "match the syntax of a universal character name" because it contains universal character names as its substring.
I also thought that "match" may mean that the entire token produced via concatenation stands for one universal character name, and that therefore this undefined behavior isn't invoked in this code.

Reading [PRE30-C. Do not create a universal character name through concatenation](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/PRE30-C.+Do+not+create+a+universal+character+name+through+concatenation), I found a comment saying this kind of concatenation is allowed:

> What is forbidden, to create a new UCN via concatenation. Like doing
>
> assign(\u0001,0401,a,b,4)
>
> just concatenating stuff that happens to contain UCNs anywhere is okay.

And a log that shows that [a code example like this case (but with 4 characters)](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=30605322) is replaced with [another code example](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=32244087).

Does my code example invoke some undefined behaviors (not limited to ones invoked by producing universal character names via token concatenation)?
Or is this a bug in clang?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the gcc 5.3.1 looks a lot worse... uncomment the `//printf("%d\n", CAT(\u306d, \u3053));` line and it complains. With clang I get consistent results at least - I can uncomment all lines and it accepts it, since the result of using `CAT` is consistently different from direct concatenation.

Comment: @grek40 gcc 6.1 is not complaining about it, seems a but in gcc 5.3.1 (not tried) ?

Comment: trigraphs, digraphs, UCN... just say NO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is not triggering the undefined behavior you mention, as universal character name (6.4.3) not being produced by token concatenation.

And, according to 6.10.3.3, as both the left side and the right side of operator `##` is an identifier, and the produced token is also a valid preprocessing token (an identifier too), the `##` operator itself not trigger an undefined behavior.

After reading description about identifier (6.4.2, D.1, D.2), universal character names (6.4.3), I'm pretty sure that it is more like a bug in clang preprocessor, which treats identifier produced by token concatenation and normal identifier differently.

Comment: +1, precisely this. 5.1.1.2 doesn't say that you can't manipulate whole UCNs in the preprocessor; It says you can't craft UCNs from their constituent parts (e.g. crafting a UCN as a consequence of `\U30 ## 53` is illegal). Long story short, GCC is doing this right and Clang is not.